# How to put a email address into item of response to be submitted to a google form?

Tags: email, google-apps-script, response, google-forms, onsubmit

A requirement has been made if  google form can handle 20000 submits within 10 minutes. To test the scalability, I need to make a simulation.

The form contains of 5 items(questions) in which one is a email address.

I am making random data, creating a response and submit to a form.

However, I can not insert the email question into the response. It seems the form response only contains 4 questions. It seems the email address item is not in the questions.

I tried to get the response from the e event passed to onsubmit. It again does not contain the email address item.

Anyone here has tried this before? Or do you have any idea ?

Thanks in advance,

Thomason

Comment: Can you add any details like code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: The option "Collect email address" is not a question, but part of the form settings. Thus, you can't "answer" it with Apps Script.

Comment: Thanks for your comment!!   Finally, after I created another form which "Collect email address" NO in the question "Email Address", I was able to capture the email address that user had entered. It meets my requirement.